# Where to set loop for updating CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

New to Python; any suggestions on formatting, simplicity, pep, appreciated.

Attempting to make a script that searches for an ID in a CSV, updates a record of that item in the same CSV, then loops through additional IDs.

If I place the 'for this_item' loop inside the 'open with' command, the nested 'for row' loop does not run a second time. I assume this is because the read iteration has already been used once. If I place the 'for this_item' loop around the 'open with' command, I get: "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file".

Additionally, this will be used on CSVs with up to 4,000 rows and as many as 30 columns- should I be concerned about the amount of re-writing that occurs?

```
from datetime import  date
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import csv
import shutil

data = [['SKU', 'Color', 'Season', 'Angles', 'Delivered'], ['A1234', 'Red', 'Week 1', 'On-model, Pinup'], ['B4321', 'Black', 'Week 2', 'On-model'], ['JJ4567', 'Blue-Multi', 'Week 1', 'Pinup'], ['ClassicTee', 'Pink', 'Week 3', 'On-model, Pinup, Detail']]
fields = data[0]


# Write Demo CSV
with open('SKU_test.csv', 'w') as csv_file_write:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file_write, delimiter=',')
    for row in data:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)

test_csv = 'SKU_test.csv'

temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False)
today = date.today()

search_items = ['B4321', 'A1234']

for this_item in search_items:

    with open('SKU_test.csv', 'r') as csv_file, temp_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=fields)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames=fields)
        # reader_lists = list(reader)
        # print(reader_lists[1])

        for row in reader:
            print(row['SKU'])
            if row["SKU"] == str(this_item):
                print(f'Search match: {row}')
                row['Delivered'] = str(today)
            writer.writerow(row)
    shutil.move(temp_file.name, test_csv)
```

Comment: Do you really need to loop through the search items? Why not just check if the current item is in `search_items` in a single loop?

Comment: `if row["SKU"] in search_items:`

Answer (score 1):

Just process the file once for all the search items, instead of looping over the search items.

```
search_items = {'B4321', 'A1234'}

with open('SKU_test.csv', 'r') as csv_file, NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False) as temp_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=fields)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames=fields)
    # reader_lists = list(reader)
    # print(reader_lists[1])

    for row in reader:
        print(row['SKU'])
        if row["SKU"] in search_items:
            print(f'Search match: {row}')
            row['Delivered'] = str(today)
        writer.writerow(row)
shutil.move(temp_file.name, test_csv)
```